# Send Json Array from Android Device to Mobile Azure Services backend javascript not working

Tags: c#, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

How to send Json array to backend javascript in mobile azure services from Android device.

Below is the c# coding from windows store app which is working correctly.

Question
Sign in to vote
0
Sign in to vote

How to send Json array to backend javascript in mobile azure services from Android device.

Below is the c# coding from windows store app which is working correctly.

```
JArray jsonArray = new JArray();
            jsonArray.Add(JToken.FromObject(new Contact() { Name = "Clarke", ContactNo = "123456" }));
            jsonArray.Add(JToken.FromObject(new Contact() { Name = "Jordan", ContactNo = "4513264" }));

JToken x = await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync("userservice/UploadContacts", jsonArray);
```

When i test through Fiddler its working correctly. But when i send from android device i am getting the data in the server as

**{ values: [ { nameValuePairs: [Object] }, { nameValuePairs: [Object] } ] }**

the number of records are matching but the instead of actual data i receive nameValuePairs: object.

Below is the android coding.

```
    JSONObject job = new JSONObject();

    Contact c1 = new Contact();
    c1.ContactNO = "9067655676";
    c1.Name = "abcd";

    job.add(c1);

    Contact c2 = new Contact();
    c2.ContactNO = "999999999";
    c2.Name = "efgh";

    job.add(c2);

    JSONArray book = new JSONArray(job);

    MobileServiceClient mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
         "https://MyAppService.azure-mobile.net/",
          "myKeyValue", context);

    mClient.invokeApi("userservice/UploadContacts", book, Contact.class , new ApiOperationCallback() 
    {
             //onCompleted callback code..............
    });
```

**Contact class has 2 properties ContactNO, Name**

Someone please help me solve this problem........

Comment: Can you post your actual code?  The code above has syntax issues (missing semicolons, etc) and won't compile.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have updated the Android code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure there is no way your code would compile like that. At any rate, you probably want to do something like this:

```
JsonArray jArray = new JsonArray();

Contact c1 = new Contact();
c1.ContactNO = "123455";
c1.Name = "Test";

Gson gson = new Gson();
jArray.add(gson.toJsonTree(c1));
Contact c2 = new Contact();
c2.ContactNO = "23455";
c2.Name = "test2";
jArray.add(gson.toJsonTree(c2));

mClient.invokeApi("uploadContacts", jArray, new ApiJsonOperationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JsonElement jsonElement, Exception e, ServiceFilterResponse serviceFilterResponse) {
```

Note that you're adding the elements to a JsonArray not a JSONObject.  You want to make sure you're using the com.google.json library for this.

Comment: Yes, but you need to go in and accept the answer as solved (it will mark it with a Green check mark under the vote count in StackOverflow)